# Monitor SSIS dataflow with equivalent of SET STATISTICS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm trying to compare statistics between SQL Server T-SQL and SSIS

Say I have the following script:

```
INSERT INTO [myDB].dbo.finalTable WITH (TABLOCK)
   (id, description, value)
SELECT a.id, a.description, b.value
FROM [anotherDB].dbo.sourceA a
INNER JOIN [anotherDB].dbo.sourceB ON a.id = b.id
```

So, it just joins a couple of tables from a seperate database and writes some data to finalTable

If I want to look at scans, reads, writes, CPU time, elapsed time and IO I can just use:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

Now, if I take an entirely different approach and create a SSIS package with a dataflow task.

Then add the source (anotherDB]) and destination ([myDB]) connections.

Then just add the T-SQL as the source code and map everything

How do I monitor the same statistics?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) (note I have no experience with it, as the office isn't (yet) running a version that supports it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Larnu . I took a look at query store yesterday and it seems to provide different results to set statistics (a lot different) so I didn't feel I could trust it with SSIS

Comment: By "same statistics" do you mean the same SQL statistics, or do you mean the equivalent types of performance metrics that SSIS generates? SSIS is very different to SQL. It's performance here is more measured more by buffers